# How do I set a the compiler option 'processor' in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, datanucleus

I'm trying to follow these instructions to configure the DataNucleus enhancer:

> If using Eclipse you need to edit your
>   project properties. Go to Java
>   Compiler -> Annotation Processing and
>   enable the project specific settings
>   and enable annotation processing. Then
>   go to Java Compiler -> Annotation
>   Processing -> Factory Path , enable
>   the project specific settings and then
>   add the following jars to the list:
>   datanucleus-enhancer.jar ,
>   datanucleus-core.jar , jdo-api.jar and
>   asm.jar **and set the compiler argument
>   processor to
>   org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerProcessor**

It was all brilliant until I got to the bold text. I can't seem to figure out what they mean. Can someone expand this sentence to be more newbie-friendly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in ANT:

```
<javac verbose="on"
    srcdir="${src.dir}"
    destdir="${build.dir}/${context.path}/classes"
    debug="${compile.debug}"
    debuglevel="${javac.debuglevel}"
    optimize="${compile.optimize}"
    deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
    source="1.6"
    target="1.6"
    failonerror="true">
    <compilerarg line=" -processor org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerProcessor" />
    <compilerarg line=" -proc:only" compiler="javac1.6" />
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is in:

```
Java Compiler
  Annotation Processing
    => Process options
    key= processor
    value=org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerProcessor
```

[image]

This is the only place where you can enter such an argument, and it is compliant with the DataNucleus compilation instruction that you mention in your question, about the [Automatic invocation from javac (*annotated classes only*)](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/enhancer.html#javac):

> If using Eclipse you need to edit your project properties.
>   Go to  `Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing`  and enable the project specific settings and enable annotation processing.
>   Then go to  `Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing -> Factory Path`  , enable the project specific settings and then add the following jars to the list:
>
> - datanucleus-enhancer.jar,
> - datanucleus-core.jar,
> - jdo-api.jar and
> - asm.jar
>
> **and set the compiler argument  processor  to `org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancerProcessor`**

The fact those instructions are for annotated classes make them eligible for this "Annotation Processing" setting.